# Shibboleth authentication for an Angular single page application (SPA)

Tags: angular, single-page-application, shibboleth

Is it possible to use Shibboleth within an Angular4 SPA?
If yes, how?

My scenario is the following: I have a SPA that can be accessed globally without login. Certain pages should only be accessed after login with Shibboleth. Therefore I'd like to authenticate the user via Shibboleth and generate a JWT for the user, which is used to authenticate against the APIs which are delivering the content for the protected page.

The problem, I am facing is, that the user has to navigate to the shibboleth-login-page on the service-provider and therefore leave the SPA to login. So I can create a JWT on a shibboleth-protected site like `/shibprotected/getJWT`, and redirect the user there. But how do I get the token back in my Angular-application? And how can I redirect the user back to the application then?

May I use cookies for this task?

Comment: can u help me sharing the .net side controller part like how to set cookie and redirect to the angular url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finnaly I managed the task with the following setup:

1. in an auth-service I generate the login-URL, which can be referenced via `<a href="authService.getLoginUrl('/currentpage')">Login</a>`:

   ```
     getLoginUrl(returnUrl = '') {
       if (returnUrl === '' || returnUrl.startsWith('/')) {
         returnUrl = window.location.origin + returnUrl;
       }

       return environment.backend_server_url + '/shibprotected/getJWT?return_url=' + encodeURIComponent(returnUrl);
     }
   ```
2. In `/shibprotected/getJWT` (which is a page protected via shibboleth on the same server) I generate the JWT and set it to a cookie. then I redirect to return_url:

   ```
     setcookie("token", $token);
     header("Location: " . $return_url);
   ```
3. back in the angular-app I'm checking for the token in `document.cookie`

This approach has two disadvantages which are maybe unavoidable when using shibboleth with a SPA:

- Cookies required
- SPA has to be reloaded after Login

Comment: can u help me sharing the .net side controller part like how to set cookie and redirect to the angular url.